# React pagination not updating when page changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have an element in my React app that maps over a state array and returns items. I'm trying to implement pagination. The buttons to switch page and change the number of items per page work and update state properly. The element maps over the correct number of items but stays on page 1 even when this.state.page changes.

My map logic is below. The name pageCount is a little misleading, it is the number of items per page to render and it works as expected. To explain the "!this.state.pageCount", a page count of zero means display all items.

```
this.state.t.map((ele, idx) => {
                            if (!this.state.pageCount || (idx + 1 > this.state.page - 1 * this.state.pageCount && idx + 1 <= this.state.page * this.state.pageCount)) return (
```

This is very strange behavior, I have confirmed via dev tools that this.state.page does update correctly, but the map seems to always consider it to be 1. I would think it would be an error in my logic here but I can't see anything wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the problem right after I posted, there needs to be a set of parentheses around "this.state.page - 1". Order of operations was wrong.